# Counting legend items in QGIS print composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend, expression, count

Is there a way to count legend items displayed in the print composer ?

I would like to adjust by expression the number of columns of my legend based on the number of legend items.

Example : if there are 6 or less legend items I want my legend to be displayed on 3 columns. If the number of items exceeds 6 then I want my legend to be displayed on 4 columns.

You can find below a screenshot for illustration purposes which features 7 legend items with a column count of 4.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can count the number of nodes in your legend using PyQGIS like below (standalone use)

```py
project = QgsProject.instance()
manager = project.layoutManager()
layout = manager.layoutByName('myLayout')

# We consider only one legend
itemLegend = [item for item in layout.items() if isinstance(item, QgsLayoutItemLegend)][0]

# It's a tree, we should follow it recursively but did not
# want to bother: only took the first level for the example
layerTreeChildren = itemLegend.model().rootGroup().children()

# Count the number of elements in each legend block
[len(itemLegend.model().layerLegendNodes(i)) for i in layerTreeChildren]


particularLayer = next(iter(QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('my layer name')), None)

if particularLayer:
    # You could also use layerOriginalLegendNodes
    # instead of layerLegendNodes
    print(len(itemLegend.model().layerLegendNodes(itemLegend.model().rootGroup().findLayer(particularLayer))))
```

Then you will need to create a custom Python expression function to use it easily

```py
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom', usesGeometry=False, referencedColumns=[])
def countLegendElements(layoutname, layername, feature, parent):
    project = QgsProject.instance()
    manager = project.layoutManager()
    layout = manager.layoutByName(layoutname)
    itemLegend = [item for item in layout.items() if isinstance(item, QgsLayoutItemLegend)][0]
    particularLayer = next(iter(QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layername)), None)

    if particularLayer:
        # You could also use layerOriginalLegendNodes
        # instead of layerLegendNodes
        return len(itemLegend.model().layerLegendNodes(itemLegend.model().rootGroup().findLayer(particularLayer)))
    else:
        return None
```

Save the custom expression and use in the expression `countLegendElements('layoutName', 'layerName')` to get the count of legend nodes.

You can reuse this count to change conditions to set your columns number.

The limitations of my current custom function are that I suppose there is only one legend in the composer (you could change the code to search with an id for the legend instead) and I also suppose your layer name is unique (if not, the code will take the first one). I also do not care particularly about highly nested layers.